# Linux Kernel IRQ Routing with irqbalance / kernel options

Tags: linux, debian, kernel, interrupts

I'm trying to get my Xen Dom0 distributing the irqs in an smp enviroment. As far as I know there are 2 Options:

- Use irqbalance
- Configure the kernel without cpu hotplug support

My System is Debian Squeeze, Xen 4.0.4, Kernel 3.2.31.

My Problem is:

- irqbalance segfaults due to a changed /proc/irq* layout or irq0 missing (this seems to be a very old bug existing since Lenny)
- To configure a kernel without cpu hotplug support you must disable cpu powermanagement which seems to be impossible through the standard wys (make config / make menuconfig) - the option CONFIG_PM simply defaults to "Y".

Any idea anyone on how to get a debian dom0 kernel with a proper irq distribution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ingrid says: You shall limit your cpus to use irqbalance:

XEN commandline **failing** to start irqbalance under squeeze:

```
/boot/xen-4.0.4.gz dom0_mem=2597152 no-bootscrub dom0_vcpus_pin
```

Working commandline:

```
/boot/xen-4.0.4.gz dom0_mem=2597152 no-bootscrub dom0_max_vcpus=2 dom0_vcpus_pin
```

Tested with 3.2.30 and 3.2.31.